# Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching

Tags: javascript, react-native

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react- 
router-dom'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import About from './About'
import Home from './Home'
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>

      <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>}/>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

**Navbar.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
       <ul>
        <Link to='/'> <li> Home </li> </Link>
        <Link to='/dashboard' > <li> Dashboard </li> </Link>
        <Link to='/about' > <li> About </li> </Link>
        </ul>   
    </div>
  )
}
export default Navbar
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <h1> this is the Home page </h1>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

**About.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <h1> this is the About page </h1>
      
    </div>
  )
}
export default About
```

Dashboard.js

```
import React from 'react'
const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> i am from Dashboard </h1>
    </div>
  )
} 
export default Dashboard
```

**i did not get any terminal error but i am getting error when i executing in browser can anyone help me how to solve this?**

**Browser throwing this errors i did not understand why it is happenning

**Compiled with problems:
s can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/in**

[image]

Comment: Is the syntax right for `App.js` on line no. 5 on `<NavBar />` instead of `< NavBar />` in original source code?

Comment: i tried just now but no change same error

Comment: What is your `react-router-dom` version?

Comment: {
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "create-react-app": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0"
  }
}